# Access items from array within object property using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create a simple category with items kind of setup, where the categories will be all my albums with all the tracks. I've tried to set it up like this:

```
enitoniApp.controller('musicItems', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.albums = [
        {
            name: 'Over The Mountains',
            tracks: [
                {
                    name: 'Over The Mountains',
                    ref: 'otmt',
                    released: 0,
                    price: 0,
                },
                {
                    name: '!C3',
                    ref: 'ice',
                    released: 0,
                    price: 0,
                }
        ]
    }
    ]
}]);
```

and in the view:

```
<body>
    <div id="allMusic" ng-controller="musicItems">
        <div id="albums">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="album in albums">
                    <div class="title">{{album.name}}</div>
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="track in albums.tracks">{{ track.name}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The expected behaviour is that angular.js will repeat the `li`'s inside the album `li` based on how many tracks, which in this case is two. However, I cannot get it to access the amount of array items inside `tracks`.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
<body>
    <div id="allMusic" ng-controller="musicItems">
        <div id="albums">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="title">Over The Mountains</div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Over the mountains</li>
                        <li>!C3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inner `ngRepeat` should be `track in album.tracks` (you have *album**s***):

```
<li ng-repeat="track in album.tracks">{{ track.name}}</li>
<!-- extra "s" was here -----^ -->
```

Comment: Oh wow now I feel stupid. Thanks for the help, didn't realize I could reference from the earlier ng-repeat. That's a neat trick.