# Weird bug with ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

So I've used `ng-repeat` to create a list of all my songs in an album (refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776769/access-items-from-array-within-object-property-using-ng-repeat/31776807#31776807) question I asked earlier)

So what I am trying to do now is make it so when a user clicks an item from the list, it plays the refered track. This is my app:

```
    enitoniApp.controller('musicItems', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.ngplaySong = function (ref, name) {
        playSong(ref, name)
    }
    $scope.albums = [
        {
            name: 'Over The Mountains',
            price: 0,
            tracks: [
                {
                    name: 'Over The Mountains',
                    ref: 'otm',
                    released: 0,
                },
                {
                    name: '!C3',
                    ref: 'ice',
                    released: 0,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Dark Clouds',
                    ref: 'clouds',
                    released: 0
                },
                {
                    name: 'Fog',
                    ref: 'fog',
                    released: 0
                }
        ]
        },
        {
            name: 'test-album',
            price: 5000,
            tracks: [
                {
                    name: 'test',
                    ref: 'null'
                },

            ]
        }
    ]
}]);
```

As you can see, I'm trying to call a regular function using ng-click. This regular function (`playSong()`) is inside the code for my player, and it plays a track based on the reference id.

snippet from player.js:

```
/** Play single song **/

function playSong(ref, name) {
    showPlayer();
    clearPlaylist()
    playlistPosition = 0;
    addToPlaylist(ref, name, 'play')
}
```

So I have this in my html:

```
        <li ng-repeat="album in albums">
            <div class="info">
                <p>{{album.name}}</p>
                <p>{{album.price | currency}}</p>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li ng-animate="grid-fade" ng-repeat="track in album.tracks">
                    <div class="grid-item" ng-click="ngplaySong('{{track.ref}}','{{track.name}}')">
                        <div class="cover">
                            <img ng-src="/img/covers/art_{{track.ref}}.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="info">
                            <p>{{track.name}}</p>
                            <p>{{track.released}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

**The weird thing is that even though this is rendering correctly:**

[image: html]

***THIS*** gets outputted into the console even though the parameters are correct:

[image: error]

Why is it not binding the data when the function gets called, am I missing something here?

Comment: ng-click="ngplaySong(track.ref,track.name)" just use ng-click like this and try

Comment: inside ng click no curly braces is needed .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that you need those braces inside your `ng-click`. Try this:

```
<div class="grid-item" ng-click="ngplaySong(track.ref, track.name)">
```

The thing is that you pass an expression to `ng-click` which is then parsed by Angular and it is smart enough to recognize the variables from current scope. You can read more on Angular expressions here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

In fact, there is a very nice and easy example in Angular `ng-click` documentation which includes accessing a local variable inside the `ng-click` expression: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. For some reason this works even though the data is not shown in the html? I am so confused, do you have an explenation?

Comment: I added a brief explanation to the answer

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the help, this was driving me nuts.